# Oracle Cloud: Joining Cash Management to Subledger and GL Tables

Tags: oracle

I'm currently working on a query in which I need to join up a few cash management tables (CE) to our subledger tables (XLA) and finally to our general ledger tables in Oracle Cloud.

Everything that I've researched seems to indicate that I need to use the subledger table “xla_transaction_entities”. However, in my particular case no data seems to be populating within this table. I'm not sure if this is a configuration issue on our side or not.

Essentially, I'm looking for very specific fields from CE (bank name, bank account number, deposit number, etc.) and our GL tables (ledger currency, ledger amounts, etc.).

I'm quite new to Oracle Cloud, so any guidance would be extremely helpful! Thanks!

Below is a sample query I started developing, but again no data within "xla_transaction_entities"

```
select gl.name Ledger
FROM
ce_external_transactions cet,
ce_statement_lines csl,
ce_statement_headers csh,
xla_transaction_entities xte, ---- problem child
gl_ledgers gl
gl_je_headers glh,
gl_je_lines gll,
gl_code_combinations glcc
gl_je_sources_tl js
WHERE xte.application_id = 260
AND xte.entity_code = 'CE_EXTERNAL'
and gl.Ledger_category_code = 'PRIMARY'
and js.language ='US'
and nvl(xte.source_id_int_1,-99) = cet.transaction_id
AND cet.STATEMENT_LINE_ID = csl.STATEMENT_LINE_ID
AND csl.STATEMENT_HEADER_ID = csh.STATEMENT_HEADER_ID
AND xte.ledger_id = gl.ledger_id
AND gl.ledger_id = glh.ledger_id
and glh.je_header_id = gll.je_header_id
and glcc.code_combination_id = gll.code_combination_id
and js.je_source_name = glh.je_source
```

Essentially these are the fields I am looking for:
[image]